# AppleScript to save selected emails from Outlook to a designated folder on my computer

Tags: applescript, ms-office

My company recently switched from PCs to Macs. I am very new to AppleScript. I have been trying to cobble together a script to save selected emails from Outlook to a designated folder.

So far I have the following which gives a Syntax Error - Expected end of line, etc. but found an identifier.

```
-- Prompt the user to choose a folder to save the emails
set saveFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select a folder to save the emails"

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    -- Get the selected emails
    set selectedEmails to selected objects
    repeat with theEmail in selectedEmails
        -- Get the subject of the email
        set emailSubject to subject of theEmail
        
        -- Generate a unique file name for each email
        set timeStamp to do shell script "date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
        set fileName to emailSubject & "_" & timeStamp & ".eml"
        
        -- Save the email as an .eml file in the selected folder
        save theEmail in saveFolder as "eml" with name fileName
        
    end repeat
end tell
```

I also have tried the following code that runs with no errors but doesn't actually save anything to the prompted folder.

```
-- Prompt the user to choose a folder to save the emails
set saveFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select a folder to save the emails"

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    -- GET SELECTE EMAILS
    --set messages_ to the selection
    set selectedEmails to selected objects
    
    --ITERATE THROUGH THEM AND SAVE THEM
    repeat with theEmail in selectedEmails
        
        set theMsg to item i of selectedEmails
        
        -- Get the subject of the email
        set emailSubject to subject of theEmail
        
        -- Generate a unique file name for each email
        set timeStamp to do shell script "date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
        set fileName to emailSubject & "_" & timeStamp & ".eml"
        
        
        set textPath to saveFolder & fileName as string
        save theMsg in (textPath)
        
    end repeat
end tell
```

I have tried different iterations of the two and don't seem to be making any progress.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I hate to say but I kinda miss VBA.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm not where I can test this atm... and don't use Outlook.  So this should be interpreted as general commentary for Applescript)

Your "save theEmail" line in the first example is not right. `fileName` should be the complete pathname for the file you want the email saved in.

ref Outlook AS dictionary:

> save v : Save an object.
>
> > save specifier : the object to save, usually a document or window
> >
> > > [in file] : The file in which to save the object.
> > >
> > > [as text] : The file type in which to save the data.

Your second example doesn't specify the path correctly, you are not adding a path separator between the path specification and the filename.

I'd probably use POSIX path too.

Comment: I made some progress. How do I add a reply with the new code? I have one script that will save the first email with the file name I want (date stamp included) but then errors out. I have another script that will save all selected emails but doesn't include the date stamp in the file name.

Also, the scripts only run if I switch to the old Outlook interface. The new interface doesn't appear to allow scripts to run yet.